# Jquery Mobile - custom transitions

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, transition

I'm working with jquery mobile library...
Couple of days a go...I ran into a dojo mobile library.
In this library there are some transitions that do not exist in jquery:
"cover", "reveal" ....[Dojo Mobile Showcase](http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/mobileGallery/demo-iphone.html)

Is there any way to create a custom transition in jquery mobile or change a little bit
the existing ones?

Where do I start? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have put together fiddle with custom transition.
http://jsfiddle.net/nachiket/3BJ5C/

Documentation for jquery mobile transition: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-customtransitions.html